# Segmentation fault cpp using vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm having a segmentation fault that I can't understand what is the exact problem.
I'm iterating over some folders that each folder have some files that i get a data from and construct an objects from that, (Ship is the object that i need details from the files to construct).

so I have a vector of vectors that contains path object (from file system library).
In the first iteration, things work fine, but on the third iteration, I get a segfault on the vector directories[2]. I thought I might try to access a memory that doesn't exist but I have printed the address of this memory and it exists furthermore the object does exist in directories[2] when I try to reach it.

first here is a snippet code of the seg fault from the gdb -

```
    Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004d8190 in std::vector<Container, std::allocator<Container> >::operator[] (this=0xabababababababf3, __n=1) at C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1043
1043        return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n);
```

Here's my code with comments so it would be easier to follow -

Thanks!!

**EDIT**
I have solved it, the problem was in other field in my code.

Comment: Put a `try...catch` around `at` and see what's reported.  `at` is expected to throw.  Also, what do your other 2 functions look like, is it init'd properly?

Comment: I think the crash happens somewhere in `extractArgsForShip`, you have `for` loop that assumes that the passed argument `folder` has 2 items. Maybe it doesn't, who knows. If I were you I'd use a debugger to step through the code until the vector throws an exception - this will save you a lot of time guessing where this problem is.

Comment: @E.vanPutten i know where it crashes... it crashes when it try to call extractArgsForShip for the second time, it isn't even getting inside.  regarding the folder has 2 items, it's irrelevant for my question as the seg fault happens before it even reaches,further more my initialization makes sure each directory[i] in directories contains at least 3 elements.

Comment: But how do you explain that the debugger says you are accessing item number 2 (so the vector was accessed [1])?

Comment: What also looks scary is the address of the vector itself (0xababababab...) that is a value which usually indicates a bad pointer. So the whole vector lives in some kind of no-mans land.

Comment: The funny thing is that you deleted your code *for privacy putpose*

Comment: Are you aware this existed? 
     https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61087120/revisions